# Need help with the superlative form of my sentence

Tags: grammar, words, verbs

I need a bit of help with my Japanese. 
If I want to say:

> Castle X is beautiful.  Among all the castles in the world, castle X is the coolest.

Is this sentence written correctly?

> しろ　Xの　ほうが　きれいで　せかいの　すべての　しろの　なかで、　しろ　Xが いちばん　かっこいい　です。

Comment: 1) `Castle X is beautiful, among all the castle in the world, castle X is the coolest` is run-on sentence.  2) [Direct translation requests are off-topic](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/799/78).  Please edit your question to include something more specific.  For example, what difficulties you are having with superlatives, etc.

Comment: You cannot use ～～のほうが because it is used only for a comparative (A is prettier than B.).  Change the のほうが to はとても and your whole sentence will be just perfectly correct.

Answer (score 2):

Castle X is beautiful. Among all the castles in the world, castle X is the coolest.

X[城]{じょう}はキレイです。世界[中]{じゅう}の[城]{しろ}の[中]{なか}でX[城]{じょう}が一番カッコイイです。

In Japanese, if the word is very common and the kanji is too complex to write they write it using katakana, just as I did with キレイ and カッコイイ.　This helps kids and teenagers who usually know the word because they hear and use it all the time, but are not very familiar with kanji.

Comment: It is は, not が in the first sentence.  In the second, 間には makes no sense; It should be either 中で or 間で, especially the former.